# C error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'char**'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void convert(int type, double amount, double rate);
int get_type(char* string);

void convert(int type, double amount, double rate) {
printf("%.2f %s is %.2f %s\n", amount, type == 1 ? "dollars" : "euros",amount * rate, type == 1 ? "euros" : "dollars");
                  }

int get_type(char* string) {
int i, c;
for (i = 0, c = string[0]; c != '\0'; c = string[i]) {
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        string[i] -= 'A' - 'a';
    }
}
return !strcmp(string, "dollar") ? 1 : !strcmp(string, "euro") ? 2 : 0;
         }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    assert(argc != 2 || argc ==4);
if (argc == 4) {
    int type = get_type(argv[1]);
    if (type == 0) {
        printf("%s is an invalid currency type. Use dollar or euro.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    convert(type, atof(argv[2]), atof(argv[3]));
}

if (argc == 2) {
    FILE* fd;
    fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
char* typestring = (char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));

    double amount, rate;
    int matches, type;

    while (!feof(fd)) {
        matches = fscanf(fd, "%s %lf %lf\n", &typestring, &amount, &rate);
        if (matches != 3) {
            printf("Line was not formed correctly.\n");
            continue;
        }
        type = get_type(typestring);
        if (type == 0) {
            printf("%s is an invalid currency type. Use dollar or euro.\n", typestring);
            continue;
        }
        convert(type, amount, rate);
    }
    free(typestring);
}


if (argc == 2 && argc != 4) {
    printf("Usage:\n\tmoney-exchange [dollar|euro type] [double amount] [double rate]\n");
    printf("\tmoney-exchange [FILE]\n");
    printf("Examples:\n\tmoney-exchange dollar 10.50 0.92\n");
    printf("\tmoney-exchange euro 5.99 1.09\n");
    printf("\tmoney-exchange prices.txt\n");
    return 1;
}
return 0;
     }
```

In function 'main':
47:4: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
    matches = fscanf(fd, "%s %lf %lf\n", &typestring, &amount, &rate);

Why is this happening?

Comment: What about the code you show is C++? Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: Change `&typestring` to `typestring`

Comment: As for your problem, `printf` doesn't work like `scanf`. The error message should be pretty clear what you need to do (the `printf` call expect `char *` and you give it `char **`, now think about it for a little while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The %s format specifier requires the corresponding parameter to be a pointer to a character array, not a character string, and it is your responsibility to allocate a character array that's large enough for it. So the corresponding parameter must be `typestring` rather than `typestring`.

You have allocated the `typestring` to be a big enough array for up to 15 characters, but there's nothing really in the code that verifies that the file will not contain a larger string, in which case you will end up with memory corruption and undefined behavior.

For this reason, the `scanf` family of functions is usually not the most robust or the recommended way to parse untrusted input. As you are learning C and C++ right now, it is important for you to understand this topic, in order to avoid committing more serious mistakes of this nature, in your future career.

Answer (score 0):

typestring is a char*,which is what the %s specifier is for, but you are providing &typestring, and by including the & this makes it a char**. Pass typestring without the & and your compiler error should disappear, but the answer about ensuring adequate size is relevant here, so check into that!